# Highscore with PlayerPref c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I recently started coding and it's my first project in C# and Unity too. So my question is probably easy to solve, and there could some bad errors. So I'm open for ideas or explanations.

So I tried making a Script to save my Highscores in the PlayerPrefs and display them while I play my 2D endless runner. (Similar to the dinogame in Chrome)
The "normal" score worked, but I can't seem to make the Highscore to show up. Does anybody know where I went wrong or how I could make it in a easy way?

I already have a image + text in my canvas(as I've seen it online for the normal score display) and added it, and this (below) is my code for the highscore.
I wasn't able to find any explanations to solve it online, if you know any sources, I'd be happy to read and learn more.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms.Impl;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HighScore : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text HighscoreText;

    
    private void Start()
    {
       
    }
  
    void StoreHighscore(int newHighscore)
    {
        int oldHighscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Highscore",0);
        if (newHighscore > oldHighscore)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Highscore", newHighscore);
    
        }

    }

    void Update()
    {
     HighscoreText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("newHighscore") + " Highscore";   
    }
}
```

I added the PlayerPref.Save() in my GameOver Script. To save the PlayerPrefs before reloading the scene as a GameOver.

Thank you

Comment: I think the problem comes from `void Update()` you try to get `PlayerPrefs.GetInt("newHighscore")`, but you set `Highscore` above, not `newHighscore`.

Comment: What about the overall design, you should note that `void Update()` function is called every frame in your game (so about 60 times per second you update text, though it doesn't change that frequently. Instead, you better assign new text right in `void StoreHighscore(int newHighscore)`, when condition `newHighscore > oldHighscore` is true.

Comment: Furthermore no need to make storing of high score that complex. You can make a normal variable near `public Text HighscoreText;`, but it would be `public int Highscore;`, update it instead. You can make it a C# property as well, so instead of having `StoreHighscore` function, you would have a property which would transparently handle updating of text right when you `set` it.

Answer (score 2):

```
void Update()
    {
     HighscoreText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("newHighscore") + " Highscore";   
    }
```

Simple mistake, you just tried to get the PlayerPref with the Key "newHighscore" but that key doesn't exist since when you used PlayerPrefs.SetInt you passed the Key "Highscore".

To solve this, simply try to get the right Key:

```
void Update()
        {
         HighscoreText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Highscore") + " Highscore";   
        }
```